# iOSの特定の端末にプッシュ通知出来ない

Tags: ios, push-notification

Apnsを使用していますが
特定の端末(端末の設定等は他の端末に合わせてあります)で4G通信の場合に通知が届きませんでした。
特定の端末でWi-Fiを使用している場合プッシュ通知が届きました。
他の端末では4Gを使用している場合でもプッシュ通知が届いています。

●特定の端末の情報です。

- iOS Ver : 10.1
- iPhone model : ME337J/A
- (iPhone5s)

■モバイルデータ通信

- モバイルデータ通信:ON
- 通信のオプション: ローミングオフ
- インターネット共有:ON
- モバイルデータ通信を使用:ON
- Wi-Fiアシスト:ON
- ネットワーク選択
  →自動

■通知設定

- 通知を許可:ON
- 通知センターに表示:ON
- サウンド:ON
- Appアイコンにバッジを表示:ON
- ロック画面に表示:ON

■お休みモード:OFF

特定の端末にプッシュ通知が届かないのはなぜでしょうか。
端末の設定等は合わせてありますが少しでも心当たりのある原因等ありましたら教えていただきたいです。

---

コメント欄が見ずらい為こちらに追記します。

> １．開発上で、バージョンが古いアプリがインストールされている
>   　　→ 証明書が変更された後にインストールを行っていない。
>   　　→ 本番orデバッグ、一致しない通知を投げられている

最新のアプリがインストールされていることを確認済みです。
証明書等変更されてから数日後にインストールしている為問題ないと思います。
通知は本番のものを使用しています。

> ２．保存したトークンが不一致

サーバー側、アプリのログを確認し、トークンが一致していることを確認しました。

> ３．同時に送信した数が多い(最大送信バイト数に頭打ち)

同時に送信した端末数は３台で、送信した内容としてはタイトルに４文字本文に４文字です。

> ４．通知を許可していない

通知を許可していて、通知スタイルはバナーに設定しています。

> ５．通信状況が悪い

キャリアの通信ですが通信状態は良好でした。

---

iPhone本体の端末設定の
通知→通知スタイル(アプリ毎)→ロックされていないときの通知のスタイルを
「バナー」から「なし」に設定後、通知が届くようになりました。
この現象について記載されている
公式のドキュメントや参考サイト等ありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 他、プロファイルが古い、デバッグトークンとプロダクショントークンが混じっている、証明書が不正、送信時のパスワード不一致など基本的なことから色々思いつきますが、証明書の生成方法や、通知の送信方法なども記載した方が正確な情報を伝えることが出来るかと思います。現状ですと、当てずっぽうに"ここを確認してください”としかいえません。

Answer (score 0):

検証した内容などあれば記載していただき、
内容をもう少し、絞れないものでしょうか？

思いつく限りですが、

１．開発上で、バージョンが古いアプリがインストールされている
　　→ 証明書が変更された後にインストールを行っていない。
　　→ 本番orデバッグ、一致しない通知を投げられている
２．保存したトークンが不一致
３．同時に送信した数が多い(最大送信バイト数に頭打ち)
４．通知を許可していない
５．通信状況が悪い

などなど

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。  実際にプッシュ通知を確認しているのはテストフライトにアプリを上げて確認していますので本番用の証明書を使用しています。  Wi-Fiの場合はプッシュ通知が送信できている為デバイストークンは合っていると思われます。  同時に送信した端末数は3台です。  通信状況は問題ないと思われます。